# Where is the DataTable Data? Does it clear on the return?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a method that populates a DataTable. It is doing that fine. I made the variable Public so I could use it again.

When I go to use the data later on the Save method the DataTable no longer shows any rows.

How do I persist the DataTable better?

```
    public DataTable dtHeadCats = new DataTable();
protected DataTable GetContentHeaders()
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ToString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdHeaderCats = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sdaCtats = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdHeaderCats);

            cmdHeaderCats.CommandText = "uspGetData";
            cmdHeaderCats.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cn.Open();
            sdaCtats.Fill(dtHeadCats);
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
    return dtHeadCats;
}

protected void multiFileUpload_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
{
    // various logic... but the dtHeadCats is now empty..
    DataView dview = new DataView(dtHeadCats);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems issue is that you are not [persisting state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx) of `dtHeadCats` between your post backs. Try store that in `Session`.

Comment: And you managed to infer that it's an ASP.NET project solely from the existence of the `FileUploaded` event handler -- kudos!